# Field aliases with Mongoid and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

It's common practice in MongoDB to use short key names to save space.  For example, one might want to use "fn" instead of "first_name"

However in your app, you're screwed if you use "fn" all over the place.  It's too ugly.  For Rails specifically, is there an easy way to specify an alias when declaring a field in Mongoid?

Also, does anyone know of any open source sample projects that use Mongoid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

you should consider using

```
 field :fn, :as => :firstname
```

as outlined here:
http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/ce3298d6a167bd70

this is a very good practice which is fully supported in mongoid.

Comment: The idea is that your app code calls `firstname` and not `fn`. Mongoid just stores the field internally in mongo as `fn`.

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen short key names in any MongoDB projects, so I wouldn't say it's common practice. I don't think you'd see a noticeable speed improvement and it would complicate your code unnecessarily. Descriptive names are good so long they aren't so descriptive that it takes you forever to type.

There's lots of MongoDB open-source projects. Just do a search on github.

-- edit below --

This was a pretty opinionated answer. Overwriting the processing methods (https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/attributes/processing.rb) as described in other answers is more appropriate in the scenario where you MUST have small field names.

Comment: It's not a speed issues, it's a space issue. There is a big difference between storing "first_name" and "fn" a billion times (~10GB vs ~2GB). If you're running on commodity hardware, space is cheap, but if you're running on server grade hardware, space is expensive. See: http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/23/on-shortened-field-names-in-mongodb/

Comment: The only time I would see shortening field names necessary is when: 1) Small values, 2) Very large dataset, 3) Very loose schema (adhoc fields). Given those 3 cases I agree that overwriting the processing methods make sense (as answered below). Even then you'll have to keep it in mind when querying as well, so you're producing quite a bit more complicated code. For example if I have a really large dataset, small values, but my schema will almost never change (like tracking stats) then I'd probably opt for postgresql instead of mongodb.

Comment: Pretty sure the folks at 10Gen (the company behind MongoDB) disagree[1] with Dave Rapin's opinion. Not only, as @Intelekshual mentioned, can you realize significant disk space savings, but Mongo needs to store your working set and indexes in memory. Smaller documents means you can store more in memory, not to mention the performance increases your app code gains by not having to handle more bloated mongo docs  

  [1]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-optimize-storage-use-for-small-documents

Comment: This is an old answer, but hopefully this clears up the understanding - the main reason you'd ever want to use short field names in MongoDB is to avoid the 16MB BSON document size limit. However in practice, this may not be useful for you. It's very specific to the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in your class file. (It hasn't been tested in all cases, just passing a hash into create or update.)

```
  field :fn, :type => String

  alias :first_name :fn
  alias :filtered_process :process

  def process(attrs = nil)
    attrs[:fn] = attrs[:first_name] unless attrs.nil?
    filtered_process(attrs)
  end
```

Comment: Mongoid 3 has built in support for field aliasing, so you don't have to employ ruby's method-cache-destorying alias method.