# MongoMapper syntax error on hyphenated key name

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Trying to setup a MongoMapper object for a Document with a key named 'buy-only'. When I try to start the application, I'm getting this

```
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting ';' or '\n'
          def buy-only       ^
(eval):3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:88:in `module_eval'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:88:in `create_accessors_for'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:27:in `block in key'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:25:in `tap'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/keys.rb:25:in `key'
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/protected.rb:20:in `key'
```

Here's my definition for the key in my model:

```
key :'buy-only', Boolean,
```

Seems like MongoMapper is trying to auto generate a function to handle the key buy-only, and since the hyphen is not valid syntax, it's failing. Is there any workaround for this error? Please do not question the use of hyphen in Mongo's attribute names. If I could change that, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I think you're out of luck unless you want to hack the MongoMapper source to, say, add a `:name => 'buy_only'` option to `key` or hack it to use something other than `module_eval` to create the methods. There's no "don't add methods if they're already there" so you can't hack in a `define_method('buy-only') { ... }` call before the `key` to stop it from trying to create the methods itself.

Comment: Can you switch to Mongoid? Not only is it still supported but it seems to [allow key aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6713113/479863).

Comment: Hey @muistooshort thanks for your comment. I think I have a work around. I created plugin called custom_key which is basically my implementation of the key method in which I enabled an :as parameter when defining the key. That worked for me. But thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

MongoMapper won't properly currently support keys with hypens, since it's going to attempt to create accessor methods for those, and `buy-only` is not a valid method name in Ruby.

However, I have a branch that should hopefully be merged to master shortly which includes key aliasing. This would let you do something like:

```
key :buy_only, :alias => "buy-only"
```

You can find the branch here: https://github.com/cheald/mongomapper/tree/alias_keys

Comment: That's exactly what I did to remedy this problem too. However, I've come to realize that it's not an acceptable solution just because it's so prone to 'schema change' in mongodb. All it takes for the code to break is for someone to add another field that has '-' in the field name. Even if the attribute is not listed in the MongoMapper model, it would still break when MongoMapper tries to serialize the resultset into an object in ruby.

Comment: I've solved that via this commit: https://github.com/cheald/mongomapper/commit/550b88f32054e021ae2b18ff1515ae6856977498 -- it'll be merged to master shortly.